# LDA - Linear discriminant function

Tags: r, statistics

What is the formula used to compute the posterior probability for LDA in R ?
I have a unbalanced class 97% to 3%. Does LDA is good in this case ?

Comment: Cross-posted on SE: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178981/lda-linear-discriminant-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When covariance matrices of the two classes are unequal, a (class) unbalanced data set have a negative effect on the performance of linear discriminant analysis (LDA).
After fitting LDA by using library `MASS`,you can apply a 70% threshold (as your data is unbalanced) to the posterior probabilities and then sum those probabilities to classify your data.

```
sum(lda.pred$posterior [ ,1] >=.7)
```

Comment: I am trying to train a model in R and use the results to compute discriminant score and posteriors in SQL. What is the formula used in R to compute posterior so I can replicate this in SQL.  Any reason to use 70%? In my dataset I have 97% of dependant variable falls in class 0 and 3% in class 1.can I adjust prior in lda() to account for this or can I use upsampling

Comment: pk(x) as the posterior probability that an observation X = x belongs to the kth class.